# How to manage AWS e2 CPU and memory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu

Is there a way I can manage the AWS cpu and memory usage of one e2 instance? So that for example, the cpu or memory wouldn't go over 80% usage and not below 30% either.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? Can you explain why do you want the CPU and/or memory kept between 30% and 80%?

Comment: The only way to ensure that CPU won't go above a certain level is to kill the processes that are above that level. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @mostafazh Its for a school project, were moving the old server to a the AWS server and its a requirement for the application.

Comment: @kdgregory I was thinking the same thing also too

Comment: @EzeAhuna Did you take in your class "auto scaling groups"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add more resources. By scaling automatically when your usage goes beyond threshold.
2. Track the top processes causing high resource use and [nice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice)ify them.

   2.1. If the processes being nice are still being bad enough, kill them.

Problem with 2 is course that you might kill something very useful/required if you only go by numbers.

Comment: I like the first option. I think its more suitable for my situation